# Concept of web.config file in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

Could you please tell me how we will use more than 1 web.config file in asp.net?

Comment: Can you explain a bit why you want to use more than one web.config file? What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: this is the requirement of our project, we are developing our website

Comment: yes, but for what purpose? You can put different web.config files in different directories for security settings and similar. You can also break out portions of a web.config into other config files and reference them using the `configSource` attribute, in order to break up a large config file into smaller pieces. These two serves completely different purposes. So the question is: for what purpose do are you planning to use several config files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple web.config in different directories in the web application. This will help you to override any parent folder config settings

[Multiple Web.Config files in ASP.NET web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681664/multiple-web-config-files-in-asp-net-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use multiple web.config files as far as I know.  You can however run create a new website that uses a different web.config file and has duplicate files.

If there is a particular setting you want to be variable, then your design sounds a bit inefficient and you should probably be handling those values outside the web.config file.

You can also split your config file into multiple parts, which is useful if it's hard to manage and want to modularise it.  Do as follows:

Your **Main.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="YourSettings.config" />
  <system.web>
    <!-- Continue as normal -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then create **YourSettings.config**

```
<!-- Referenced by Web.config -->
<appSettings>
  <add key="Key" value="MyVal" />
</appSettings>
```