# Edit Web.Config after publishing in asp.net IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a developed a application in c#,asp.net web application(using only inside our company) and finally am deploying the application in server PC (different host and port )allocated for this purpose.

When i developing or maintaining the application in my PC, having different host and port, every time when i need to publish im changing the connection string in web.config and and copying app folder in server PCs, interpub->wwwroot.

Is there any option to avoid each time changes? i.e, for publishing i will use seperate web.config and for developing work i use seperate web.config.

Server PC- web.config, connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=192.168.3.5;user id=root;password=sim;database=simpayroll;allowuservariables=True;port=3306"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="simpayrollConnectionString" connectionString="server=192.168.3.5;user id=root;port=3306;password=sim;database=simpayroll;persistsecurityinfo=True;allowuservariables=True"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />    
  </connectionStrings>
```

My local Web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=simpayroll;allowuservariables=True;port=3306"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="simpayrollConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;port=3306;password=root;database=simpayroll;persistsecurityinfo=True;allowuservariables=True"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: kindly hide credentials if they are important like pwd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882425/can-i-have-multiple-web-config-files-in-a-single-web-project

Comment: @utility I suspect OP is asking about [web.config transformations on publishing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) rather than multiple config files.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes i thought OP needs to have multiple configs as i was unclear just put in comments :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [web.config transformations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) to over come with your problem

In your **Web.Release.Config** file,

`<connectionStrings xdt:transform="Replace">
    <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="your connection string"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="simpayrollConnectionString" connectionString="your connection string"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>`

Comment: Sorry. i have only one web.config file. When i see in solution explorer,single file is there. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Ok.Now i converted my application VS2010,now i can see that 'Add coding Transforms' option and two config files are there.May be in VS2008 this option is not there

Comment: Great, and If you use higher version of the VS than it's already comes with three config files.