# Access multiple web config file in Asp.net (c# 5)

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an application where i have 2 folder  called Production and Development.i have placed my web config files there.

Based on configuration like if it is my development machine my development web config file should be accessed and all my variables should be read from there.
Same in case of production folder.

Appreciate any help on this

Thanks

Kumar

Comment: That's what config transforms are for.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882425/can-i-have-multiple-web-config-files-in-a-single-web-project .