# How do I modify web.config locally without letting TFS check it in?

Tags: tfs

We have a project with a web.config that has a connectionstring to the in-house database.
I am working from home and I want to modify web.config to access my local SQL server instance.
I do NOT want to check in this change and make all the other developers have to change it back.
I do NOT want to remove web.config from tfs, I just want to keep a local copy on my home machine that does not always want to check in.
I also do NOT want to have to remember 50 times a day to uncheck web.config from check-in.

I have tried the remembering route, it doesn't work for as many times as I check in.
I looked from some kind of flag that would make it ignore my local changes to web.config.

I expect to be able to modify web.config, and mark it so that tfs will not automatically check it in until I specifically tell it to.

Actual results: I check in my local copy about 6 times a day by accident.

Comment: What about other parts of `web.config` that may changes and not related to `connetionstring` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't prefer to change behavior of TFS.
Instead I can suggest you to [work with multiple web.config files](https://deanhume.com/working-with-multiple-web-config-files/); that there is a **Add Config Transform** option on right-clicking on `web.config` file.

Side-note: `web.config` has many parts and if you don't want to care about changes of connection-strings only please [separate your config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889492/4519059).