# How does everyone manage developer environment config files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-config, app-config

We already use **web.config/app.config** xml transforms to for our .NET projects and are also using multiple **appsettings.js** files based on an environment variable for .NET CORE projects.

What I'm looking for is some sort of way our developers can have their own config transforms on their local machine. Something like the .NET core environment variable would be awesome - but I haven't been able to get this to work in XML land. The older way of doing it only seems to work on publish, and having build tasks to transform the configs has proven a bit messy - maybe I missed something.

We are currently trying to exclude our configs from the commits (and usually failing) which is a pain to manage when the config file changes quite often. We have 6 config files in the solution.

My question to you is

- How do other development teams manage this?
- What is the best/cleanest way to handle each developers connection strings ect without having to manually file compare before each commit.

Comment: See these links, you might get some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882425/can-i-have-multiple-web-config-files-in-a-single-web-project 
https://deanhume.com/working-with-multiple-web-config-files/

Comment: @AbhinawKaushik Thanks for the links, but as explained, web.conf transforms only work on publish. If we hook it up to a post-build task then we still end up with the issue of having to exclude the transformed file for each commit. Due to our continuous integration implementation, we don't separate out our appsettings and connection string as they are changed using config transforms when they are automatically deployed - thus I have asked here for an alternative.